# Solving x's at y for quadratic given one point, origin at (0,0)

Tags: geometry

I have a parabola where I know the origin is $(0,0)$, I know a single point, and I know it's symmetrical on the Y axis. I only need positive or negative $x$, I can work with either. It has been a couple decades, I am rusty.

Given any other $y$, I want to find $x$.

So far, I think I'm getting $a$ correctly. For my known $(x,y)$ point I plug them into:

$$a = y / x^2$$

Then I'm trying to use that $a$ value to find $x$ given $y$.

I think, given $0 = (b + sqrt(b-4ac)) / 2a$, I'm trying to find an X-intercept given the Y-intercept is at $(0,- y)$, basically an offset of my known $y$. Then $b$ is zero, because the origin X is at 0, but this may be where I'm going wrong?

$$0 = sqrt(4ac) / 2a$$

Where $c$ = $-y$. I guarantee that $y$ is the negative number, so no imaginaries under the sqrt.

So for known $c$ and $a$, that should give me $x$?

But the values I'm getting don't line up with visual parabola I have. *(Full disclosure, this is a programming thing, I'm trying to make some things line up with a half-parabola-curve where all I really know are width and height (x and y), that it's symmetrical, and starting at 0,0. I know various vertical positions of the things I'm trying to line up horizontally.)*

Comment: Is the origin part of the parabola? Then $c=0$, and the problem is solvable. You are given $(x_0,y_0)$, and a point $(x,y)$, but in the second case you only know $y$, and not $x$. Then write $a$ in terms of $(x_0,y_0)$ and in terms of $(x,y)$. You will get $$\frac{y_0}{x_0^2}=\frac{y}{x^2}$$You have only one unknown, so it should be easy to solve. Don't even need the quadratic equation, just take a square root.

Comment: So using $h/w^2 = y/x^2$  should be like $$x = sqrt(y/(h/w^2))$$? (not sure how to do the subscript things)

Comment: $\displaystyle a = \frac{y}{x^2} \implies x^2 = \frac{y}{a}.$

Comment: @RandyHall correct. Use `$x_0$` to get $x_0$, and `$\sqrt{\frac{x_0^2 y}{y_0}}$` to get $\sqrt{\frac{x_0^2 y}{y_0}}$